# type 'List<dynamic' is not a subtype of type <List<String> in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

I am tryiong to display a list of events a user has registered for in a flutter app but i keep getting this error even though I am following the tuorial closely. I believe the error might be in the following lines but I have checked multiple times but havent gotten a fix.

```
        ref.watch(userEventsProvider).when(
              data: (events) => Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: events.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    final event = events[index];
                    return ListTile(
                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(event.images),
                      ),
                      title: Text('/r${event.name}'),
                      onTap: () {},
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              error: (error, stackTrace) => ErrorText(
                error: error.toString(),
              ),
              loading: () => const Loader(),
            ),
```

I have tried following the tutorial but theres seems to be no fix.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the issue might be with the `event.images` field. it's actually a list of dynamic objects.

```
CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(event.images[index]), // Corrected line
),
```

Replace index with the appropriate index

Answer (score 0):

```
ref.watch(userEventsProvider).when(
              data: (events) => Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: events.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    
                    return ListTile(
                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(events[index].images),
                      ),
                      title: Text('/r${events[index].name}'),
                      onTap: () {},
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              error: (error, stackTrace) => ErrorText(
                error: error.toString(),
              ),
              loading: () => const Loader(),
            ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).